# Using WordPress to control one page (blog/news feed) on website

Tags: php, wordpress, blogs, feed

### A Little Information

I have built a bespoke website that has nothing to do with wordpress, the root directory looks something like this:

```
domain.com/            // index.php
domain.com/about/      // about.php
domain.com/contact/    // contact.php
domain.com/news/       // news.php
etc...
```

However, I would like to use WordPress to control the content on one page within the site (`domain.com/news`) whilst keeping the current website design on this page.

I have started by installing WordPress to a sub-directory here `domain.com/_wp/`. I am not too sure where to go next...

I do not want WordPress to have anything to do with the pages on my site, apart from the `domain.com/news` page, but as I am unfamiliar with WordPress, I do not have any idea how to do this.

I have looked around the web at particular forums, but none of them really make sense to me:

1. http://wordpress.org/support/topic/can-i-use-wordpress-on-only-part-of-my-website-and-design-the-rest-in-dw
2. http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page

### My Question(s)

I will write the code to retrieve the 'News Feeds' from the WordPress database on the `domain.com/news/`, but in the meantime I would like to know the following:

1. At the moment, there are a lot of sections in WordPress that I don't need, like 'Pages' etc. How can I strip WordPress down to include only the **Blog Editing** tools?
2. What section should I be using to add posts to my 'News Feed'? I assume I should be uisng the 'Posts' section but I just want confirmation :-)
3. WordPress has applied one of its themes to the site in the Appearance tab, should I just be ignoring this? Should I also be ignoring Widgets and menus etc as they have nothing to do with the content being posted?

***I apologize for all of the above questions, WordPress is a little more complicated than I originally thought it would be. I have tried to solve all of the above myself, but sadly have not had any success, and I hope all I need now is just a pointing in the right direction***

Comment: You could install wordpress to /news and change the theme to fit your sites' design. As the wordpress database structure can be a bit complex you should use the built in methods to retrieve a post. Posts and pages are quite similar in wordpress, stripping down the base install to less functions is not easy (and bad for updates).

Comment: @SvenSchneider Yes, but how do I install it do just /news? Does that mean I have to have duplicate code so I have `domain.com/news.php` and `domain.com/_wp/themes/news.php`?

Comment: You would have the whole installation in /news. So there is a index.php which is the wordpress index.php. This will show your  posts made in wordpress. And you are free to post only news there.

Comment: @SvenSchneider I appreciate your help, but that doesn't really make much sense to me. I am able to post news in WordPress already... My problem is that WordPress is using its 'twentytwelve' theme, not my page... and I have a lot of menu options that I do not want...

Comment: So this is totally different to what you asked before... This should answer almost every question on how to change the layout, where the layout resides and how to display only posts: http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

Answer (score 1):

From the [WordPress documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website), to display posts only:

```
<?php
require('/the/path/to/your/wp-blog-header.php');
$posts = get_posts('numberposts=10&order=ASC&orderby=post_title');
foreach ($posts as $post) : start_wp(); ?>
<?php the_date(); echo "<br />"; ?>
<?php the_title(); ?>    
<?php the_excerpt(); ?> 
<?php
endforeach;
?>
```

Now to trim the irrelevant sections in WP default themes (`/wp-content/themes/YOURTHEME/`), you may either comment them out in the misc .php included templates, or using theme management.

Considering how you don't wish to integrate much in WordPress, only displaying posts would make the most sense.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be along the right lines +1 ... Do I HAVE to place my page within the 'YOURTHEME' directory?

Comment: not if you dont wish to rely on WP at all. only post through the admin, load posts from whichever page you desire & set its theme/css on that one, in you example: /news.php

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way is to install Wordpress to a subfolder called news, and have it set up there.

So you will have:

```
index.php
about.php
contact.php
news.php
```

and a folder named news

Since the links you have 
`domain.com/news/` 
are probably rewritten through apache, apache will now to get first the folders and if none found, then make the rewrite. So it will work from the start.

Comment: Why does having WordPress installed in a sub-folder called 'news' make any difference? When I click 'Preview' where will that take me???

Comment: Yes, it will take you directly to /news/, but the answer above is better if you just want to use a wordpress separately and only point to it in a custom php file. However, the above example will only make you A page, and if you want to point links to single news pages, the wordpress will point you to the initial install, and if that's somewhere else than the news subfolder, you will not have the same consistency in links.

Answer (score 0):

a very simple way of doing is making a iframe for you site that would just pull the wordpress site into your news page.

`<div style='width: 900px; Height: 300px; Overflow: hidden;'>
 <iframe style='width: 918px; Height: 300px;' src="https://www.wordpress.com/" 
frameBorder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</div>`

you could also use margin controls to just display a small part of the page. 
`margin-top: -50px;`
for example would cut off the head.

However this would slow down your site slightly as it having to run a whole subpage on your page, but if its just for one page it might be ok.